# Call WebService (asmx) from winfor with https, not working

Tags: c#, iis, https, asmx

We are converting our old webservices (asmx) to use https, trying to get it working locally.

I have a test app I wrote in winforms jsut to call the service.
Trying to modify it to call via https, following this pattern
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/751059/Call-https-Webservice-in-Console-Application

(Not sure I trust this pattern 100%, but it's a place to start, looks like it's trying to ignore all errors)

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TrustAllCertificatePolicy();
        }

        public class TrustAllCertificatePolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy
        {
            public TrustAllCertificatePolicy()
            {
                AdStudent.ADStudent ws = new AdStudent.ADStudent();
                ws.Url = "https://localhost/JCDCADStudent/ADStudent.asmx";
                try
                {
                    string str = ws.GetGuidString("Brown.Eric");
                    MessageBox.Show("secure guid is  " + str + ".");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string cleanMsg = GetCleanMsg(ex.Message);
                    MessageBox.Show("\n\n          " + cleanMsg + "\n\n\n\n\nProgrammer Msg:\n\n" + ex.Message, "Error");
                }
            }

            public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp, X509Certificate cert, WebRequest req, int problem)
            {
                return true;
            }

            private string GetCleanMsg(string message)
            {
                string startTag = "<ClientMsg>";
                string endTag = "</ClientMsg>";

                Int32 start = message.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length;
                Int32 end = message.IndexOf(endTag);

                try
                {
                    return message.Substring(start, end - start);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return "UNABLE TO PARSE MESSAGE : \n " + message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the exception
{"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."}

inner exception

The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

When I try and just run the HTTPS in the browser, it complains that like the title or subject field is not formatted correctly. but If I tell it to ignore that it opens the web service, I'm guessing that is the problem,

[image]

How do I fix it?

How do I get a better error like the one the browser gives me, to report in my app?

The cert was provided by our IT team, I'm not sure I can get it changed, it's a long-standing cert used for Dev.
Maybe I can get it regenerated correctly (it's applied to our machines via network policy)

Comment: You will have to reveal more about that certificate using a report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure" error, it is likely that your server certificate is self-signed, or you have used the wrong host name to connect (the host name must match the name on the certificate), for example imap.example.com and example.com may point to the same server, but certificate is issued only to imap.example.com and this is the address you should use), so please check the certificate in your IIS.

Comment: The cert was created in such a way that it was named *.bob.org, so i had to call the webservice wtih a non localhost address machinename.bob.org style.